# jQuery hide button if textbox is empty and display if textbox have value

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to disable add to cart button when checkbox is checked and text box is empty. If user click on checkbox and type anything in textbox, button will appear. Otherwise it will be disabled.

I am adding a class "disableit". My code is almost working: when user types anything in textbox button appears, but when again textbox goes empty class "disableit" not adding again.

What I want, if user click on checkbox add to cart button will not work until user fill info into textbox and if user uncheck checkbox textbox will hide.

```js
jQuery('.single-product .summary button.single_add_to_cart_button').addClass('disableit');
jQuery(".custom_enter-the-domain-name,.custom_hosting-username").on('propertychange change keyup paste input', function() {
  if ((jQuery("input[name='addon[domain]']")).is(':checked') && (jQuery('.custom_enter-the-domain-name').length > 0)) {
    jQuery('.single-product .summary button.single_add_to_cart_button').removeClass('disableit');
  } else if ((jQuery("input[name='addon[domain]']")).is(':checked') && (jQuery('.custom_enter-the-domain-name').val() == '')) {
    jQuery('.single-product .summary button.single_add_to_cart_button').addClass('disableit');
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What WE want is that you add the relevant HTML to the snippet I made so we have a [mcve]

Comment: So does the user have to check the box AND add text or will you check the box when the user types and uncheck it when it is empty? you want to do sometning like  `$("input").on("input",function() { $(this).closest("parentContainerIDOrClass").find(".single_add_to_cart_button").prop("disabled",this.value=="")}`

Comment: create a fiddle and share the link, its easier for everyone.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas - even easier to stay here at SO and create a snippet

Comment: @mplungjan Oh yes !

Comment: I don't about your layout but one may solution can be using CSS rules ex : .thebutton + input[type=checkbox]:checked + .thetextbox:empty

Comment: simple go to the url here http://delegatestudio.com/themes/test-theme/ you will find the checkbox domain. when you enter the text in texbox "Enter the Domain Name" add to cart button will appear. but when if you make it empty button will not hide again.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 event handlers, `input` for the text field and `change` for the checkbox. The following code will accomplish the behavior you want.

```
var addToCart = jQuery('.single-product .summary button.single_add_to_cart_button')
var checkBox = jQuery("input[name='addon[domain]']")
var textField = jQuery('.custom_enter-the-domain-name')

function toggleButton() {
  if(checkBox.is(':checked')) {
    if (textField.val() === '') {
      addToCart.addClass('disableit')
    } else {
      addToCart.removeClass('disableit')
    } 
  } else {
    addToCart.addClass('disableit')      
  }
}

toggleButton()
textField.on('input', toggleButton)
checkBox.on('change', toggleButton)
```

Comment: problem the disable it class not removing on input textbox http://delegatestudio.com/themes/test-theme/

Comment: Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/82wn2fcd/ Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: exactly same but the code is not working on my live page.